# Is there a better way to perform a query like this in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a model called `User` and each user has a list of another model called `Hobbies`. I want to retrieve a `User` who has a hobby with a certain ID, is there anything better using Entity Framework than just retrieving all users then searching inside each user's hobbies list and match it with the hobby id, a pseudo code would look like the following

```
UserList = select all users from db 
targetUser = null;

for User in UsersList:
    for Hobby in User.HobbiesList:
        if(Hobby.ID == currentHobby.ID)
        {
           targetUser = User;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post pseudo code. It only obfuscates what you really want. Show your own first effort in *running* code, even when it's still premature.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, EF won't automatically get all the linked entities, you need to explicitly `Include` everything you want to see in the end result.

As for the question, yes of course, you can use all the standard LINQ filters when working with EF. In your case

```
db.Userlist.Where(user => user.HobbiesList.Any(hobby => hobby.ID == currentHobby.ID))
```

Don't forget to `Include(user => user.HobbiesList)` if you want to see it in the results.

Comment: or `db.Hobies.Where(h => h.ID = id).Users`